# Does the limit API return any status code if the daily API limits of organization have exceeded?

Tags: rest-api, limits

We want to make sure that if we have exceeded the daily API limits, we don't proceed further. So we are using the limit API for the same. Does it return any status code when the organization has exceeded the daily API limit something like 503? Salesforce documentation hasn't explicitly mentioned it anywhere.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_errors.htm

Do we have something like that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: [UI API Dev Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_intro.htm) states the following; **The User Interface API uses the Salesforce API limits. When you exceed the rate limit, all User Interface API resources return a 503 Service Unavailable error code.**. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried exceeding the daily limit in my developer org. So, when the daily API limits of the organization were exceeded, I tried hitting the API again. I got the error **Total request limit exceeded** with **403** status code which is also correct as per the screenshot attached below from Rest API Guide.

[image]